# LOAD DATA IN FILE where to put file on server

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I am using load data in file command of mysql with the help of following syntax

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www//Distivoc.txt' INTO TABLE `cds_distivoc` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Right now i am using LOCAl Keyword because it copy the file temporary on server and execute the command.

Query:Where to put the file on server if i dont want to use local copy.

Answer (score 0):

> Where to put the file...

The file has to be accessed by client in case of LOCAL option or by server.

From the documentation:

> If LOCAL is specified, the file is read by the client program on the
>   client host and sent to the server. The file can be given as a full
>   pathname to specify its exact location. If given as a relative
>   pathname, the name is interpreted relative to the directory in which
>   the client program was started. If LOCAL is not specified, the file
>   must be located on the server host and is read directly by the
>   server... [more information](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)